# Creating optgroup in play framework from a query result

Tags: playframework-1.x

If for example i have the following data retreived from a database:

```
--------------------------
|  id | name | department|
--------------------------
|  1  | john | HR        |
--------------------------
|  2  | peter| accounting|     
--------------------------
|  3  | adam | secretary |     
--------------------------
```

how can i create an optgroup tag  to display this result in an optgroup to have the following:

```
 <select >              
            <optgroup label='HR'>
              <option value='1'>john</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label='accounting'>
              <option value='2'>peter</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label='secretary'>
              <option value='3'>adam</option>
            </optgroup>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the best way, but you could represent department as a model and do it this way :

**User model :**

```
public class User extends Model {

    public String name;

    @ManyToOne
    public Department department;


}
```

**Department model :**

```
public class Department extends Model {

    public String name;

    public List<User> getUsers() {
        List<User> users = new Arraylist<User>();
        if (this.id != null) {
            users = User.find("department.id is ?", this.id).fetch();
        }
        return users;
    }

}
```

Then in your view you can generate your select box list this way

```
<select>
    #{list departments, as : 'department'}
        <optgroup label="${department.name}"">
            #{list department.users, as : 'user'}
                <option value="${user.id}">${user.name}</option>
            #{/list}
        </optgroup>
    #{/list}
</select>
```

Like I said, perhaps there is a better way, (maybe using raw sql queries...)